# Data returning value from select box in multi languages while it is in english

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, date

I am using Zend form for booking website, where booking Date as SELECT BOX input type, and the date formate is like MMMM d, yyyy 'Sun 09 Sep, 2012'. but i received the values in multi langauges .. like in french, arabic, etc while the date values in the select all in english.

I need help in this please can you let me know how to force it as it is in english.. or give me posible solutions. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code to the form and perhaps from your translate plugin?

Comment: i am not using translate plugin. my form is an english and generic for all languages should show in english. but i am geting different formate e.g like this ١٠/٠٩/٢٠١٢ in arabic while my form value is 10/09/2012

Answer (score 0):

Here a couple of simple solutions using [Zend_Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.filter.set.html)

```
$date = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('date');
$date->setLabel('Date');
$date->setAttrib('placeholder', 'DD/MM/YYYY'); //use of placeholder text may help encourage correct format
$date->addFilter('Digits'); //Option #1 filter out all characters except digits, add formatting back in controller or model (This is the one I prefer)
$date->addFilter('PregReplace', array('match' => '/pattern/', 'replace' => '/')); //option #2 filter and replace based on preg match       
$this->addElement($date);
```